# Passing Data to Directives Asynchronously

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a handful of directives on a page that all share the same data. I have a heavy API call that needs to be made somewhat frequently to update these directives. Each directive contains the data in three states:

1. A display state showing the results and,
2. A loading state indicating that the call to the API is being made
3. An error/empty state

How the state is shown is directive specific and is not always a matter of updating some css or a variable. Sometimes it requires the calling of a function.

Trying to do this it seems I would have to listen for my trigger with a watch, then broadcast that I'm 'in loading' to all my directives. Then broadcast that the resource was loaded to resolve the loading state if it succeeded, else broadcast that there'd been an error. That's a lot of different broadcasts and 'on's in all my directives. Is there a more efficient way invoking direct methods on child directives?

Comment: I dont think you need a watch. You should only listen with $on in the directives and make the service broadcast those events - like you said - this answer shows how to do it [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16863919/2927409)

Comment: I could have clarified: I use the watch to keep an eye on a variable that triggers the need to make the call.

Comment: Use a shared service to share data, which would effectively remove broadcast/on events